# programatically disable a button on a jquery ui dialog until ajax call complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using [jquery ui dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons), and one of the button's causes an ajax call which takes a few seconds so I want to disable the button after I click it until the ajax call return (then i will enable it).

From googling, I see a few others asking this question but the answers seems very outdated and hacky (based on very old versions of jquery ui). So I was hoping that there was a more elegant way to do this now

How can I programmatically disable or enable a button on an jquery ui dialog?

Comment: please share your jquery-ajax-call source code and the binding to your button; that would help me to create an implementation for what you need

Comment: just disable the button right before you launch the ajax call, and then re-enable it after you get the ajax result..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

- the pressed button will be disabled
- a deferred promise will wait until the until the `ajax()` call is complete
- then deferred action will re-enable the button

::

```
buttons: {
    "DoAjax": function( e ) {
       //disabling button clicked
       var btnAjax = $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('DoAjax')");
       btnAjax.disable(true);

       $.when( $.ajax( "/api/controller/action" ) )
            .then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                 // re-enable pressed button
            btnAjax.disable(false);
            })
      }),
     "Close":

    }
```

Comment: spot on chap! except `$('this')` should be `$(this)`. Correct me if I am wrong but `$('this')` will look for the DOM element `<this>`

Comment: @Adjit, great catch. Thats what I get for cut-and-paste!

Comment: Glad to help! :) we are all victims of cut-and-paste errors

Comment: You should really use `prop()`rather than `attr()`/`removeAttr()` these days.  However the main problem is that the OP wants to enable7disable a button on a jQuery UI dialog.  Those buttons are created programatically from the `.dialog()` call and don't have foreseeable ids to bind to

Comment: @DaveA: No, they do not want to disable all buttons (as I read it). They want a specific button to be disabled when that button itself is clicked.  Your post at the time I commented was binding via ID (`$('#btnDoAjax').click(function(...`) and my comment was that the buttons on a jQuery UI dialog do not have id to bind to.

Comment: I don't think your current version works either - `this` in the dialog button callback (when you set the attr) is the dialog itself, not the button.  And isn't `this` in the ajax request callback (when you remove the attr) the ajax request? I don't think it is the button anyway, and I don't think that the `this` you are removing the attribute from is the same `this` you added it to.

Comment: @Adam, I think you're right. I should change my selector to be a derivative of the event. Good catch. Thanks!

Comment: $.ajax returns a promise, so there is no need to wrap it with $.when.  Also, currently the button won't be enabled if the $.ajax() call fails.  So you'll be better off to do $.ajax(...).always(function() { btnAjax.disable(false); });

Comment: @StepanRiha, that's interesting. I knew it had a promise that worked on success and fail conditions, but I didn't know about `always`. will look into it

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "I've read and understand this": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        //disabling button after 3 seconds
        //for all buttons
        setTimeout("$('.ui-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled')", 3000);
        //for first button
        setTimeout("$('.ui-button').first().attr('disabled', 'disabled')", 3000);
    }
});
```

View demo: http://jsfiddle.net/renishar/db5SX/373/

in this the button programatically disabled after 3 seconds.

Comment: but your code would disable every button. I want to only disable a single button

Comment: for first button: $('.ui-button').first().attr('disabled', 'disabled')

Comment: Even the "first" variant disables the first .ui-button on the page, not in that dialog doesn't it?  Also the question was to disable a button *when it is clicked* and then re-enable it *when it gets an answer*.  Not disable all buttons after a given time (whether clicked or not).  It's a good solution but for a different problem:)

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to get the button from the event argument to the button's callback function and disable it.  You then save the button in a variable and re-enable in the callback to the ajax request.

For example, with HTML:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <div id="message">
       Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

You can do the following:

```
var n = 0;
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Close": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        'Slow': function(e){
            n++;
            $('#message').html('Fetching...' + n + '...');
            var button_clicked = $(e.currentTarget);
            button_clicked.prop('disabled', true);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/echo/html/',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {
                    html: 'Updated text',
                    delay: 3
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $('#message').html(data);
                    button_clicked.prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

THe button clicked is disabled while the ajax request is running and enabled again when it answers (you should really add an error handler as well of colurse).  I added the counter to illustrate it - clicking while the button is disabled does nothing.

See it working in [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/WKvQM/1/)

Comment: turns out jquery has a 'disable(true|false)' method. That works better than attr (pure JQ way always feels better). I also changed my selector to use that button classes and expected text. Thanks again for all the help,mate. Your answer helped mine. +1 for all your insights!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the button that you want to change like this:

```
var dialog = $("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "I've read and understand this": function() {

           return true;
        },
        "Another Button" :function(){return true;}

    }

});


var buttons = dialog.parent().find("button");
$(buttons[0]).click(function() {
        $(buttons[0]).prop('disabled', true);
        $.ajax({
                url: "...",
                type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {

                       $(buttons[0]).prop('disabled', false);

                }
            });
        });
```